# Stream music or audio files via Skype

Tags: unix, audio, debian

I want to stream music or audio files via Skype to another person via internet. I'm using debian squeeze. My idea: open the audio in stream for microphones etc. and adding the audio file to the stream. I don't want to use a audio in-out bridge, but a software solution. Are there any similar project? How can I manipulate the audio-in stream?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), and [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linrad is your best bet.
The Linux sound system ALSA has a mechanism by which the output of one program can be sent to the input of another program.

http://www.sm5bsz.com/linuxdsp/install/snd-aloop.htm